# Imacro : How to skip if TAG doesn't match any elements on a page?

Tags: loops, extract, imacros

I'd like my code to break the loop in case TAG doesn't match any elements in page but this doesn't work.

```
var result = "";
var counter = 1;
while(true)
{    
var ret_code = iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS="+counter+" TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://www.xxx.com/index.php?topic=*.0 EXTRACT=HREF",60);
    if(ret_code<0)
        break;
    s = iimGetLastExtract();    
    result += " "+s;    
    counter++;
}
```

The TAG code keeps running again and again instead of stopping itself if it doesn't found any matched elements.

Is it possible to use return code to do this and how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

your code will never stop because ret_code will always be 1, because you are scraping data, and even if element is not found it will success to scrape and return default value equal to "#EANF#", to make this code work as you want you need to split it to 2 steps - first step will check if element exist and second step will scrape - here is example:

```
var result = "";
var counter = 1;
while(true)
{    
iimSet("counter",counter);
var ret_code = iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{counter}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://www.xxx.com/index.php?topic=*.0");
    if(ret_code<0){break;}
iimSet("counter",counter);
ret_code = iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{counter}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://www.xxx.com/index.php?topic=*.0 extract=href");
    s = iimGetLastExtract();    
    result += " "+s;    
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER always worked for me. If element is present it will return true, if not it will return false.

Comment: never tried this, but anyway emulating mouse hovering in the browser is very unreliable, because you can move mouse over the browser and it will break hovering effect on stated element, so I don't recommend to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = "";
var counter = 1;
while(true)
{    
iimSet("counter",counter)
var ret_code = iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{counter}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://www.xxx.com/index.php?topic=*.0 EXTRACT=HREF",60);
    if(ret_code<0)
        break;
    s = iimGetLastExtract();    
    result += " "+s;    
    counter++;
}
```

I've seen this few times

```
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS="+counter+" TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://www.xxx.com/index.php?topic=*.0 EXTRACT=HREF",60)
```

But I never used that approach . So I changed it into this.

```
iimSet("counter",counter)
var ret_code = iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{counter}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://www.xxx.com/index.php?topic=*.0 EXTRACT=HREF",60)
```

Other then that I see no error in this. Try it and if it doesn't work we will try something else.